# Data is too large or too small texture2d.SetData<Color>

Tags: c#, xna, texture2d

I am trying to create a 2 textures. One used to have an image as the sprite, but I am changing it to be a solid black rectangle. I didn't get any errors until I tried to set the color for the new sprite. Then I got a "The size of the data passed in is too large or too small for this resource" exception.

```
        boostBar = new Texture2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, 1,1, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
        boostBar.SetData<Color>(new Color[] { Color.Black });
        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        myTexture = new Texture2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, 40, 40, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
        myTexture.SetData<Color>(new Color[] {Color.Black});
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `SetData<Color>` is an array where each element represents a single texel color. You are passing an array with a *single* color element. But the second texture you created is 40x40, so you are 1599 elements short of the required amount of texel data.

Thus, you're getting an exception that the data is "too small."

Create a color array that is 40x40 in size, set each element to `Color.Black` (or whatever you want), and pass *that* to SetData.

Comment: I think I understand, but when I crate a 2d array 40 by 40 and payy it in it says I cant convert Microsoft.Xna.framework.Color[*,*] to ...Color[]

Comment: You have to create a *1D* array. You've created a 2D array. You want "new Color[40 * 40]," not "new Color[40, 40]."

Comment: Ok - then do i have to make a new array like Color[] _colors = new Color[40*40]?